# Macro Excel won't past exact image to Powerpoint Presentation

Tags: vba, excel, charts, powerpoint

The strangest thing is happening with my macro in Excel. It works like a charm, but when it has to copy 2 charts and paste into my powerpoint presentation, suddenly, the Chart isn't exactly the same.

My code:

```
Set Wb = Workbooks.Open("Path\WbName.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=0)
```

It opens 5 more workbooks... And then it goes through a loop, to copy all the Charts

```
Dim Charts_Arr As Variant
    Charts_Arr = Worksheets("Parameters").ListObjects("Parameters").DataBodyRange.Value

For i = LBound(Charts_Arr) To UBound(Charts_Arr)
    SourcePath = Charts_Arr(i, 8)
    SheetName = Charts_Arr(i, 4)
    ShapeNr = Charts_Arr(i, 2)
    SlideNr = Charts_Arr(i, 3)
    Schaling = Charts_Arr(i, 6)

    Set Source = Workbooks(SourcePath)
    Set PPpres = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation
    Set Sh = Source.Sheets(SheetName).Shapes(ShapeNr)


    Sh.Copy


    Set NewSh = PPpres.Slides(SlideNr).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteJPG)
    With NewSh
      .Top = Charts_Arr(i, 5)
      .Left = Charts_Arr(i, 7)
      .ScaleHeight Schaling, msoTrue
    End With

Next i
```

This goes perfectly. But when I take a look at the ppt-file, 2 charts are not exactly the same.

*(TIP: Excel is Chartarea, not a shape - didn't know this at first)*

[image: The white line drops after 27/11]

When copy the picture manually, I get the correct picture:

[image]

And what's more bizarre, I have 2 other Charts on another Sheet in the same workbook who doesn't cause any problems.

Could this be a problem with links, or the way I copy?

> ***UPDATE***

If I adjust the code as suggested below:

```
 Source.Sheets(SheetName).ChartObjects(ShapeNr).Chart.CopyPicture
        Set NewSh = PPpres.Slides(SlideNr).Shapes.Paste
            With NewSh
                        .Top = Charts_Arr(i, 5)
                        .Left = Charts_Arr(i, 7)
                        .ScaleHeight Schaling, msoTrue
            End With
```

I get this:

[image: CopyPicture]

I'm doing something wrong with the Paste part of the code, I guess.
Tried other possibilities, always end up getting no images, or the one above.

> ***FIXERSUPDATE***

So I made/used a loophole. Couldn't find a way to paste the images directly into Powerpoint, So I pasted it into an excelsheet 'Temp' instead. And adjusted the Array, and that seemed to work. But I still would like to know how to do this directly in Powerpoint.

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Comment: Do you have a chart which matches the pasted one?

Comment: Did you try to copy the chart with copypicture method? `Wb.Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture` where 1 is the index of the chart. And instead of jpg, other paste special data types?

Comment: @TimWilliams Picture Nr 1 is the outcome after the macro, Picture Nr 2 is the original Chart.

Comment: @danieltakeshi I made an update, tnx for the tip!

Comment: @Nathalii. Unfortunately I don't use VBA for PowerPoint, however, even when I try to copy/paste manually some charts, It seems to get out of formatting. Maybe some issue between both programs. Let's try pasting another datatype, like `Set NewSh = PPpres.Slides(SlideNr).Shapes.Paste ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` or `Set NewSh = PPpres.Slides(SlideNr).Shapes.Paste ppPasteMetafilePicture`. Refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/shapes-pastespecial-method-powerpoint) for other data types.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/shapes-pastespecial-method-powerpoint

Comment: @TimWilliams, I've tried every option on that page. Doesn't seem one of them is doing what it needs. But thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a PasteSpecial Option that could fix the issue. 
CopyasPicture works, but I can't seem to figure out how to paste it directly into ppt. So I used a workaround. I created a 'Temp' Sheet, where I could paste the Chart as Picture in the right format, afterwards I could program it to paste the shape into Ppt. Not the cleanest way to solve the issue, but it works.